# Rails receive json params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm developing an application which receives some json parameters to create an object through post method, but I can't receive the parameters, I'm receiving blank parameters.

My method is the following:

```
def create
render :json => params[:name]
end
```

and my json example is the following:

```
{"name":"foo"}
```

but the problem is that it's rendering 'null'

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well for starters you are just echoing back the parameter and not actually creating anything. How are testing the controller action? With curl, postman or a controller test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For receiving JSON in the create method, you need to keep few things in mind.

Your request should include the following header

```
Content-Type: application/JSON
```

By the look of your question, you are building a API, so you have to change the `protect_from_forgery with` in your `application_controller.rb`

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```